# any books on ConText?

Tags: context

I am not able to find any books on Context on amazon. While I see many books on Latex.

But I read elsewhere that Context is a good system, so I wanted to learn it by reading a book about it.

How does one learn it if there are no books on it? What do you recommend to read to learn Context for someone who never used it before?

Comment: *How does one learn it if there are no books on it?* -> [wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page), [mailing list](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context), [source-code](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules#Self-documenting_source_code).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find printed ConTeXt books at [H2O
books](http://www.h2o-boeken.nl/product-category/context/).
Furthermore, there's a great
selection of PDF manuals [on the Pragma
homepage](http://www.pragma-ade.com/overview.htm).
Two good reference manuals
are [the revised ConTeXt user manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) and
[the MetaFun manual.](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf)

Another way to obtain working examples for a particular purpose is to
browse through questions tagged [context](/questions/tagged/context) on this site.

For more information about documentation, see
[Updated documentation of
ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51341/updated-documentation-of-context) or
[Where can I find good ConTeXt
documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/where-can-i-find-good-context-documentation).

Comment: H2O link changed: http://www.h2o-boeken.nl/product-category/context/