# ConTeXt for the LaTeX user

Tags: context, learning, tutorials, resources

I am willing to try out ConTeXt after reading about its typographical capabilities and differences from more classical engines. I was wondering if there was good and recent resources to learn the specificities of ConTeXt for people like me who already know the basics of the TeXnique.

In the question *[Where can I find good ConTeXt documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/where-can-i-find-good-context-documentation)*, there is given a link to some very good manuals. However, after parsing them, it appears that they go pretty deep from the begining or go too much into details for someone who never used ConTeXt.

So, do you know of resources that could suit my needs? Let me know if I am wrong on the resources I already find.

Comment: There are *many* links there for different purposes. I cannot see the point of this question. Good answers should be added there, not here, so that all the information is together in one place. And that question explicitly addresses the needs of ConTeXt novices.