# Is ConTeXt dead?

Tags: context, tutorials

Seaching for ConTeXt tutorials and [documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/where-can-i-find-good-context-documentation) I mostly found unfinished books older than 5 years, yet the last stable release was in 2015 and it seems widely used.

Is this the intended state? I know that ConTeXt is aimed at commercial users so online documentation might not be a priority; or maybe is it that in the last decade ConTeXt remained so stable and backward compatible that those tutorial are still valid despite the age?

Comment: Since the development of LuaTeX and ConTeXt is tightly coupled, you could probably judge (approximately, at least) the state of the one from the state of the other.

Comment: https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/commits/beta (unofficial-mirror of beta releases)

Comment: I think ConTeXt is more active than LaTeX3 ever was (mainly because it is driven by commercial demands).

Comment: @Aditya seems to me that only one person is committing to that repo. Not a very good sign imo. I would have expected ConTeXt to be much more open. Disappointing.

Comment: @user32882: ConTeXt doesn't use git for version control. The unofficial mirror is just a shell script that downloads the beta releases and uploads them to a git repo. If you look at the source files, there are significant contributions by others. [Example 1](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/search?q=Wolfgang). [Example 2](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/search?p=2&q=Taco), [Example 3](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/search?q=Alan), [Example 4](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/search?q=Mojca).

Comment: What *does* it use for version control? Also where is the official repo? Can anyone contribute?

Comment: I just found this https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-context/2020/003652.html. As long as PRAGMA maintains this stance, ConTeXt will remain a small, niche project which most developers will neglect or even actively avoid. Compare with the thriving and vibrant LaTeX community : https://github.com/latex3.