# The definitive guide to ConTeXt MkIV and LMTX documentation

Tags: context, books, documentation, tutorials

On the [mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) (sign up, do it!) and on [TeX - LaTeX
Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com) (*abbr.:* TeX.SX) I often read the complaint
that the ConTeXt documentation is bad/old/incomplete.  I
wholeheartedly disagree.  However, I have to admit that ConTeXt
documentation is actually quite *hard to find*.  That is why I have
come to the conclusion that a definitive guide to the, in my opinion
outstanding, ConTeXt documentation is necessary.  I structured this
guide in such a way that a beginner can start reading the linked
resources from top to bottom.

Even though you read the words “beta” and “experimental” in many
places, the versions provided can be considered production quality
because Pragma ADE relies on these versions for commercial purposes.
If you have a deadline coming up, I would recommend not updating
ConTeXt until you have finished your work, because some mechanisms are
moving targets anyway.

Comment: This guide is also available GitHub where you can contribute: https://github.com/hmenke/context-examples/blob/master/GUIDE.md

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Introductory material

This is the part of the documentation where ConTeXt is indeed seriously
lacking.  There does not exist much in terms of good and complete
introductory books for ConTeXt, while there exist literally hundreds of
more or less good books for [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11).  But do not despair,
there is still a way for a beginner to start getting into ConTeXt and
here is how.

1. **[A not so short introduction to ConTeXt](https://github.com/contextgarden/not-so-short-introduction-to-context)** This introductory text
   was originally created by Joaquín Ataz-López in Spanish but has since been
   translated as a community effort into several different languages.  The book
   does not assume that the reader knows anythin about TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt, so for
   already experienced readers it might be going a bit slow in the beginning.
   Other than that it is exactly what you would expect from an introductory
   textbook, as it has plenty of examples and goes into both depth and breadth
   with a large number of ConTeXt features that are accessible from the macro
   level.

When I first studied ConTeXt this book did not exist yet and I had to resort to
other resources which even in hindsight I still consider very valuable:

1. **[ConTeXt Mark IV an excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/ma-cb-en.pdf)** This is the successor
   of [ConTeXt an excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mp-cb-en.pdf) which is often put forward as
   the beginner's guide.  However, [ConTeXt an excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mp-cb-en.pdf)
   was written in 1999 for ConTeXt MkII and therefore contains a lot
   of information which is outdated in MkIV.  Some people have
   complained that the layout is horrible but I think this document
   gives a very nice overview over the most frequently used commands
   on about 100 pages.  Unfortunately I still couldn't typeset
   ConTeXt documents after reading this.  I now knew what the
   building blocks are but I still had no idea how to put them
   together.  That is where the next resource enters...

2. **[Creating a clean presentation style in 40 commits](https://github.com/adityam/context-slides-example)**
   An amazing tutorial by Aditya Mahajan where a set of presentation
   slides is built step by step.  You can either browse the commits
   on GitHub, use the `git-walk` tool (instructions provided
   on [Aditya's blog](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/presentation-40-commits/)), or view all the details [on a single page](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/presentation-40-commits-redux/).
   This tutorial equipped me with the
   basic understanding of how to customize the most relevant elements
   of the document.

3. **[ConTeXt command reference](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf)** Now that you know how to
   customize your documents, you of course want to try out all the
   different settings.  But wait, what are actually *all* the
   settings?  What are the possible keys of, e.g. `\setuphead`?  That
   is where the ConTeXt command reference comes in.  This extremely
   minimalistic document is the most helpful I have encountered so
   far.  On over 300 pages every setup command with all accepted keys
   is listed.

This concludes the section on introductory material.  From here on we
dive into more complicated topics.  Nevertheless after reading the
references (1) and (2) and having (3) at hand you should be able to
compose your first documents.

---

### Advanced

I don't recommend that you try to read these references as a whole.
There is no way you can memorize all that stuff.  Just skim through it
to get an idea of what is there, so you can come back and read in
detail when you actually need it.

You have probably started writing your own macros and are getting in
contact with the ConTeXt core and are wondering what all those weird
`\s!`, `\c!`, `\v!`, `\??` and `\@@` are.  Then you might enjoy the
[System Macros](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros) page in the ConTeXt Garden Wiki.

#### Fonts

- **[Fonts out of ConTeXt](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf)** a.k.a “the new font manual”
  supersedes the old [Fonts chapter](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-fonts.pdf).  Once in a while you
  want to tweak things like ligatures, kerning, protrusion, or even
  want to do complicated things like defining a virtual font to
  display your custom characters.  This is the go-to resource for
  all those complicated font-related questions.

- **[Typescript files](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/tex/context/fonts/mkiv)** If you only want to implement a
  typescript for a font which does not have one provided you are
  much better off just browsing the ConTeXt source for the
  [`type-imp-*.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/tex/context/fonts/mkiv) files and see how it's done there.

#### Mathematics

- **[ConTeXt rehab for amsmath addicts](https://www.ntg.nl/maps/34/06.pdf)** This is a short
  article which appeared in 2006 in the MAPS journal of the Dutch
  TeX user group.  It details how to achieve similar alignments to
  the ones known from the LaTeX `amsmath` package.  (This article
  appeared also in [My Way](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/context-latex-math.pdf))

- **[math](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/math-mkiv.pdf)** This manual discusses some advanced math stuff,
  like automatic replacements (the input `/=` is automatically
  converted to `≠`), interplay with grid typesetting, custom
  numbering, and some tricks for deficient math fonts.

#### Bibliographies (BibTeX)

- **[Bibliographies the ConTeXt way](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf)** Probably
  you read about `\setupbibtex` in [ConTeXt Mark IV an
  excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/ma-cb-en.pdf).  This mechanism has been superseded by the
  new `btx` mechanism which acts as a replacement for BibTeX,
  entirely implemented in Lua.  Thanks to `btx` ConTeXt does not
  depend on external programs for processing bibliographies.
  However, it only provides two different styles: `apa` as an
  author-year style and `aps` as a numeric style.  A verbose style
  named [`ieee`](https://gist.github.com/adityam/afda949f76676055e7906679599ec937) is in development.

#### Interaction with Lua

- **[ConTeXt Lua Documents](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf)** ConTeXt MkIV is based on
  LuaTeX and LuaTeX development is driven solely by ConTeXt.  It is
  not surprising to find that there is amazing interaction between
  ConTeXt and Lua and in principle you can typeset whole documents
  in Lua.  Some things, like the PDF backend, have spare or don't
  have macro-level interfaces at all.  Such low-level mechanisms are
  usually accessible in Lua.

#### Graphics

- **[Metafun](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf)** Metafun is a set of MetaPost macros,
  specifically tailored for the interaction with ConTeXt.  You can
  do a lot of fun things, like overlays, drawing font outlines, or
  just basic shapes.  A LaTeX user would use Ti*k*Z for that (which
  is also available in ConTeXt) but Metafun runs orders of
  magnitudes faster and integrates quite naturally with everything
  related to frames, such as backgrounds, tables, and plain frames
  of course.
- **[Flowcharts](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/charts-mkiv.pdf)** Macro-level interfaces for drawing
  flow charts in Metafun.  Flowcharts are not part of the core
  functionality and have to be imported using `\usemodule[chart]`.
- **[Nodes](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/nodes.pdf)** Macro-level and MetaPost interfaces for drawing
  commutative diagrams.

#### Layout

- **[It's in the details](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/details.pdf)** I consider this to be one of the
  most important documents for the advanced ConTeXt user.  It is a
  visual guide to all the cool features which made you switch from
  LaTeX to ConTeXt, namely grid typesetting and sidefloats.  As
  already noted, this is a visual guide and not really a manual
  which explains a lot of things.  Rather it lists different options
  and shows the visual effects of setting those options.

- **[Pages](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/pagecolumns.pdf)** Behind this rather misleading title hides
  a manual on how to typeset magazine style columns with floats
  which can span several columns.

---

### Expert

- **The progress reports** A lot of features which get added to
  ConTeXt are rather minor or affect the core directly, so they do
  not have dedicated manuals.  Nevertheless, Hans tirelessly
  documents these features in his progress reports on LuaTeX and
  ConTeXt development.  In chronological order these are:

  1. [The history of LuaTeX](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mk.pdf)
  2. [MkIV Hybrid Technology](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/hybrid.pdf)
  3. [about LuaTeX and ConTeXt](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/about.pdf)
  4. [Still going on](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/still.pdf)
  5. [on and on](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/onandon.pdf)
  6. [following up](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/followingup.pdf)
  7. [on target](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/ontarget.pdf) (current working report)

  [The history of LuaTeX](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mk.pdf) has mostly historical relevance
  because a lot of features described in there are documented
  elsewhere in much more detail, like [OpenType fonts](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf),
  [Metafun](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf), and [XML](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/xml-mkiv.pdf).

  The other documents give a very in-depth view of all the internals of
  ConTeXt MkIV and LMTX and it is definitely worth skimming through them to
  see what is available.  Whenever I open these manuals and read a few
  paragraphs I find new hidden features.

- **[Dealing with XML in ConTeXt MkIV](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/xml-mkiv.pdf)** ConTeXt can export
  documents to XML.  This is possible thanks to the monolithic core
  and unified interfaces.  It is also possible to generate typeset
  output from XML input.  This manual details all the XML
  interaction with the macro and the Lua level.

- **[LuaTeX](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/luatex.pdf) and [LuaMetaTeX](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/luametatex.pdf)** Because the relationship
  between ConTeXt MkIV and Lua(Meta)TeX is so close it is absolutely necessary
  for the expert user to know the details of the underlying engine.  The links
  point to the LuaTeX and LuaMetaTeX manuals hosted on Pragma ADE which always
  covers the latest development version used as a basis for ConTeXt MkIV and
  LMTX, respectively.

---

## Further resources

All the manuals listed above are also shipped with the installation of
ConTeXt standalone and TeX Live.  The PDFs can be found in
[`doc/context/documents/general/manuals/`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/doc/context/documents/general/manuals), the corresponding
sources in [`doc/context/sources/general/manuals/`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/doc/context/sources/general/manuals) (the
links point to the ConTeXt GitHub mirror).

In TeX Live, manuals can also be opened using the `texdoc` tool by
providing the name of the PDF as an argument, e.g. `texdoc metafun-p`
will open the MetaFun manual.

There are two other manuals which I see mentioned in some places and I
want to give my comments on these.

- **[Typographic Programming](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/style.pdf)** This is supposed to grow into a
  manual about general aspects of document design and how to
  translate design into style by the means of automated typesetting.
  At the moment it is unfinished and is mostly about
  microtypographic features and page layout but doesn't go beyond
  the much more complete [Fonts out of ConTeXt](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf) and
  [It's in the details](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/details.pdf).  It also hasn't been updated in
  a while.
- **[ConTeXt reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf)** This was supposed to be a
  comprehensive introduction to ConTeXt and could have evolved into
  a complete introductory user manual but got stuck somewhere
  halfway between MkII and MkIV with a few missing chapters.  I
  don't recommend reading it before you have a solid understanding
  of the difference between MkII and MkIV, because otherwise it is
  just too confusing.

There is also the [command reference](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Category:Commands) on the ConTeXt Garden
Wiki.  This is a total hit and miss because some commands are
documented really well, others not at all.  The good thing is that it
is publicly editable, so if you encounter bad documentation you should
log in and fix it.

Comment: Please consider to add the manual by Joaquín Ataz López shared in the list (and now in the Garden). It's a family-friendly introduction imho `:-)`

Comment: @JairoA.delRio I have to read it first.  I'm not going to recommend anything that I haven't read.

Comment: Oh, well, I didn't know about that. I hope you have some time for it.

Answer (score 3):

Definitively ["A not so short introduction to ConTeXt"](https://github.com/contextgarden/not-so-short-introduction-to-context). There are English, French and Spanish version. It's not official, but it's good enough on my opinion.

This is inspired surely from ["The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2ε"](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)

Comment: This is already mentioned in the comments under the other answer.

Comment: Where? I cannot see any reference about that

Comment: It's the first comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448812/the-definitive-guide-to-context-mkiv-documentation/606117?noredirect=1#comment1458067_448813

Comment: I have now incorporated this resource into my guide.