# ConTeXt XML: How do I typeset blank lines, leading spaces

Tags: context, xml

I have the following example, where one `<Line>` is blank and one has leading spaces. ConTeXt is ignoring the blank line and trimming the leading spaces. How do I turn this off?

```
\startbuffer[demo]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reading>
<Header>Foo</Header>
<Line>Line #1</Line>
<Line>Line #2</Line>
<Line></Line>
<Line>  Line #3</Line>
</Reading>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:initialize
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{Book|Reading|Header|Line}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:initialize}

\startxmlsetups xml:Reading
  \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:Line
    \xmlflush{#1}\par
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{demo}{}
```

[image: Normalized lines]

Comment: I'm sure you are aware of it, but for other readers it might be interesting to point out that there is an exhaustive [XML manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/xml-mkiv.pdf) for ConTeXt.  See also [The definitive guide to ConTeXt MkIV documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448812/the-definitive-guide-to-context-mkiv-documentation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\xmlflushspacewise` to obey spaces and newline inside the nodes and use `\dontleavehmode` before so that successive `\par` can't be collapsed.

```
\startbuffer[demo]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reading>
<Header>Foo</Header>
<Line>Line #1</Line>
<Line>Line #2</Line>
<Line></Line>
<Line>  Line #3</Line>
</Reading>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:initialize
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{Book|Reading|Header|Line}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:initialize}

\startxmlsetups xml:Reading
  \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:Line
    \dontleavehmode\xmlflushspacewise{#1}\par
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{demo}{}
```

[image]