# Right-align \sym in enumeration

Tags: context

```
\startitemize[before=,width=3.5em,inbetween={\blank[small]}]
  \sym{\bold{foo}} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  \sym{\bold{foobar}} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\stopitemize
```

gives

[image: output]

Is there a way to align the `\sym`s such that foo and foobar are flush against the right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `itemalign` key to change the alignment of the `\sym` text.

By default there is no space between the `\sym` text and the content for them item but you can use the `distance` key to set a value which is inserted between them.

You can also get rid of your manual font changes when you use the `symstyle` key to change the from from regular to bold.

```
\starttext

\startitemize[width=3.5em,symstyle=bold,itemalign=flushright,distance=.5em]
  \sym{foo}    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  \sym{foobar} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: If you know of any, could you recommend any resources to find similar information in the future?

Comment: @CherryMan [The definitive guide to ConTeXt MkIV documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448812/the-definitive-guide-to-context-mkiv-documentation)