# manual - How to understand ConTeXt commands?

Tags: context, documentation

The reference manual **[ConTeXt commands](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf#[0,%7B%22name%22:%22Fit%22%7D])** gives all supported options by command. Unfortunately, there is no description about the conventions used.

```
               ¹           ²
\setuphead [...,...] [..,..=..,..]
¹ SECTION     OPT
² frontpartlabel    =  name
  ...
  expansion         =  yes NO xml
  ...
  sectionstarter    =  COMMAND PROCESSOR->COMMAND
  ...
  sectionsegments   =  NUMBER NUMBER:NUMBER NUMBER:* NUMBER:all SECTION SECTION:SECTION SECTION:* SECTION:all
  ...
  referenceprefix   =  + - TEXT
  ...
  incrementnumber   =  YES no list empty
  ...
  page              =  inherits \page
  ...
  hang              =  line broad fit NONE NUMBER
  ...
  command           =   \...##1##2
  ...
```

Furthermore, we don't know anything about the options. What are these options for? How to use these options?

The notation is partially presented in **[ConTeXt MarkIV an excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/ma-cb-en.pdf)** (c.f. page 10, page 117) but the complexity of the notation (often unknown) makes the exploitation very hard.

**How to understand (know) ConTeXt commands?**

Comment: Basically this is only a reference. To understand the options, you have to hope that there is some Wiki entry or up-to-date article somewhere.

Comment: It seem that (like UNIX) ConTeX is based on an oral tradition, or "the source code is the documentation" paradigm. ;-)

Comment: There is some more detail about these things in the ConTeXt reference manual (http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) but be aware that this document is very incomplete and stuck somewhere between MkII and MkIV.  See also [The definitive guide to ConTeXt MkIV documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448812/the-definitive-guide-to-context-mkiv-documentation).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: ConTeXt source code (at least the pre MkII/MkIV code)  is very well documented with details comments explaining what the code is trying to do, commented out obvious implementations of the idea with a discussion of why the simple implementation will not work. With MkIV, the situation is not the same. It is now more like the Unix source code ;-)